# How should we deal with outdated quotes from external wiki?

Tags: discussion, external-links

[This answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7638/1398) prompts me to ask this question, though this meta discussion is about the problem in general.

In cases where the changes in the quoted sources are purely cosmetic (no change in meaning and content), the post can be edited by a simple copy/paste.

However, in the case above, the original wiki page went through a [slim-down](http://naruto.wikia.com/index.php?title=Madara_Uchiha&diff=894574&oldid=894461), which removes some of the quoted content, especially the part in spoiler.

Since it is not on the wiki anymore, I don't know whether the quoted information is still reliable or not.

The same problem happens on [Can Sasuke use Tsukuyomi?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6926/can-sasuke-use-tsukuyomi). The list of Tsukuyomi users on Naruto wiki did include Uchiha Sasuke at one point, but has since been removed.

What should we do with these posts? The obvious thing is to comment and wait for the author to edit the post, but not every user visits the site frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Usually if something is an issue, there'll be a paper trail.

If we go to the relevant [*talk page*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Madara_Uchiha) - there's only a small discussion about hair colours. The users involved don't have anything relevant on their talk pages either.

If you check the History page (or on the change itself, its just less obvious there), there's a comment by the author of the change:

> halvsies

So I imagine it was just to slim down content to the essentials. Rather than it being removed for inaccuracies

Overall, it'd be preferable if users would use the references that the wikis point to if available as they are a better source of information.

**TLDR - follow paper trail, prefer primary sources**

Comment: Let's say that the wiki decides some information is wrong. OK, they can change the information. What should we do in that case?

Comment: I guess comment and wait for the author to edit the post - and a new answer if necessary maybe?

Comment: I think there should be a way to raise a warning about outdated content, like Wikipedia, since our site deals with a lot of content which can get outdated. Comment and ask the author to fixed, as stated in the question,  is not effective for inactive users. Adding a new answer also depend on the knowledge of the person, and the editor does nit necessarily know enough about the series to put up an answer.

Comment: with the current SE system, I suppose you could place some temporary text above the quote/reference - as a warning for readers that the info is outdated. But this kind of fits into the bad rejection of edits reason 'against the authors intent'. (hopefully this would be a very seldom occurrence though and probably would have more than one person knowing about it)